# Did the rose I ordered on-line from RHS arrive dead?

Tags: shrubs

I ordered a climbing rose from Royal Horticultural website UK (Madame Alfred Carriere). It arrived at the beginning of April with absolutely no leaves or buds. It looked like a Y shaped twig in a pot. I have planted it out in John Innes no 3 against a south facing wall and kept it watered. Will I see signs of life later in the season, or was it ‘dead on arrival’??

Comment: If you gently scratch the bark with your thumbnail and see green, the rose is alive. If you see brown, that part at least is dead. Try this out on the twig of a shrub you know is alive to see what you're looking out for.